# Dynamics CRM Share Cascade Behaviour during Parent change and ReParenting

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Consider the following example in MS Dynamics CRM 2015,

Parent Entity: Account, Child Entity: Note

Relationship: Configurable cascading

- Assign - Cascade None
- Share - Cascade All
- Unshare - Cascade All
- Reparent - Cascade All

Users

- User1 is on BU1 which is under BU0
- User2 is on BU2 which is under BU0

Both users having 
 - Org level read access and User level write access on Account
 - BU level read and write access of Note

Account1 and related Note1 are created and owned by User1

Step 1:
User1 is assigning Account1 to User2. Now User2 will not get access to Note1 (As there is no Assign cascade, Note1 will not be assigned to User2 and User2 will not get even read access on Note1)

Step 2:
User1 is creating Note2 under the Account1. Now this Note2 is visible to User2 (by Reparent - Cascade all, this Note2 will be shared to User2 as he is he current owner of Account1)

What is the simplest solution to make Note1 also visible to User2?  If I change the relationship behaviour to "Assign - Casecade All", then User1 will loose access on Note1 when the Account1 is assigned to User2.

I think there is something logically missing here, when Note2 is reparented (created) to Account1, the Note2 is got shared with User2. But when Account1 is assigned to User2, the Note1 is not shared with him. I think CRM should share Note1 to User2 when the Account1 assigned to User2.

Comment: This certainly is an interesting behaviour of Dynamics CRM, but I am afraid this is not a question, it is not related to programming either and it may also lead to opiniated discussions. Maybe the Microsoft forums would be a place better suited for your post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because post is not a question, is not related to programming and is opinion-based as well.